# SQL injection possible with parameter that seems to only accept integers

Tags: injection, sqlmap, web

a similar question to this was already asked but it is not the same case. I am talking about this one [Is SQL injection possible via integer?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/142373/is-sql-injection-possible-via-integer)

In my case, I already have the confirmation of this parameter being vulnerable by someone. I'm trying with a lot of tamper scripts on SQLMap, but the only one that gave me something (that was a false positive) was space2mysqlblank.py. Whatever thing I throw at it that are not numbers gets me an error response. How should I approach this problem?